# Unable to Submit New Version in AppStore Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I trying to Submit New version in appstore. I facing below error

**English (U.S.) - What's New in This Version - This field is required**

But there is new field to enter **What's New in This Version** in appstore connect dashboard.

Any one facing issue like this.

[image: Error2]
[image: Error1]

Comment: See if you have any ad/script blockers and try disabling them. Also check the developer console for any errors or failed network requests

Comment: The error is telling you that you need to enter the information for English-us. You currently have English-uk selected where the red i icon is. Change that drop down to English us and enter the information

Comment: Are you sure you are adding a new version to an existing app? That looks more like add a new app for the first time.

Comment: Just fill in the field "What's new in this version".

Answer (score -1):

The "What's New in this Version" field should be between "Description" and "Keywords". I would try logging out and back in, or trying a different browser. Safari is always a safe bet since I'm sure Apple tests it more thoroughly than any other browser.